# Using both positive and negative values as neural network input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

In neural networks, we sometimes convert the input to z-scores. However, z-scores contain both negative and positive values, if we use such numbers as input, it seems that in some cases the neural network would not be trained well? For example, the loss function w.r.t. a weight variable in the first layer would completely flip if the input (z-score in this case) changes sign. Then the `gradient * lr` in such two training sessions would be very likely to cancel each other.

Comment: I think this problem has been answered here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/how-to-transform-inputs-and-extract-useful-outputs-in-a-neural-network

Comment: of course not, stupix downvoterx, worthlesx, ur downvx is praise, idt sht, cepu, say, do any  is perfx

Answer (score 0):

If you train a neural network on inputs, you can't simply transform those inputs without also transforming the weights and biases of the network you trained to match. The transformation you're proposing is indeed invalid.

Consider the simple case of regression where I learn a model $y = ax + b$. Now I transform my input to $z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$. It's of course not true that $ax + b = az + b$. But $y = a(z\sigma + \mu) + b = a{\sigma}z + a\mu$, and there's still an equivalent transform you would learn or just create directly if you choose to transform your input. They're all just linear transformations, after all.